nHibernate update database table after insert or update
I have this setup
Importer\Mapping\CuentaBancoMap.cs
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace Importer
{
    public class CuentaBancoMap : ClassMap<CuentaBanco>
    {
        public CuentaBancoMap()
        {
            Table("llx_societe_rib");

            Id(x => x.Id, "rowid").GeneratedBy.Identity();
            Map(x => x.Tipo, "type");
            Map(x => x.NombreCuenta, "label");
            Map(x => x.NombreBanco, "bank");
            Map(x => x.IdSoc, "fk_soc");
            Map(x => x.FechaCreacion, "datec");
            Map(x => x.Codigo, "code_banque");
            Map(x => x.Oficina, "code_guichet");
            Map(x => x.Numero, "number");
            Map(x => x.DC, "cle_rib");
            Map(x => x.Bic, "bic");
            Map(x => x.Iban, "iban_prefix");
            Map(x => x.RibDefecto, "default_rib");
            Map(x => x.ReferenciaMandato, "rum");
            Map(x => x.FechaFirmaMandato, "date_rum");
            Map(x => x.ModoDomiciliacion, "frstrecur");
            Map(x => x.Estado, "status");
        }
    }
}

Importer\Providers\BankProvider.cs
public static int AddCuentaBanco(CuentaBanco cuenta)
{
    if (dbSession != null)
    {
        return (int)dbSession.Save(cuenta);
    }
    return -1;
}

I tried to create a trigger that before or after update/insert it sets all default_rib to 0 the NEW.rowid's default_rib to 1, filtered by fk_soc, so a single client only has 1 bank account marked as default.
That's a problem because MySQL doesn't like a trigger updating the same table that launched the trigger.
MySqlConnector.MySqlException (0x80004005): Can't update table 'llx_societe_rib' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

So then I went to the C# importer app to do the same.
I was thinking I could avoid using CreateSQLQuery and writing the table name and column names written in two or three places (ClassMap and the insert/update functions) and having to chase down all those places would I need to change anything in the future.
Is there a way to do this? Something like using ORM to launch general query instead of having a single object fetched and updating only that one? Or even something simple like
UPDATE {CuentaBancoMap.TableName} SET {CuentaBancoMap.RibDefecto.Name} = 0 WHERE {CuentaBancoMap.IdSoc.Name} = {cuenta.IdSoc};

so I only have to change table and column names in the 'CuentaBancoTerceroMap.cs' file?
Another option is to fetch based on fk_soc but that's potentially multiple queries per bank per client (however many old banks the client has) instead of one for reset and one for set the new one per client.

Have you considered something like an interceptor?
That said... it looks like event listeners are the more up-to-date approach, so it's also worth looking at those.

I have not. How would I use them?

You create your own type that derives from EmptyInterceptor and then override the methods you're interested in, adding your logic. I think you want to look at the OnFlushDirty or OnSave methods.
